# Use payment service in React application

Tags: reactjs, paypal, venmo

I'm working on a course project that's very similar to UberEats or DoorDash: a customer places an order and then a dasher picks up the order to deliver it to them. We don't want to be directly handling the payments in this project, so we were hoping that we could integrate the application with Venmo or PayPal, so that when customers click a pay button, it would bring them to Venmo or PayPal with the dasher's information and expected total already filled in.

I saw that PayPal/Venmo have dev tools, but but does anyone know if this specific use case is possible?? Like could use the PayPal/Venmo dev tools without the payments going to my account and instead to another user's account (the dasher)??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You might be looking for a standard integration https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ , with a `payee` parameter in the order creation request

Comment: There is a react frontend for it, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js